# How do you create a spice model of a lm234? This model would need to be used with both LTspice and Labcentre's Proteus software

Tags: sensor, temperature, spice

How do you create a spice model of a LM234? This model would need to be used with both LTspice and Labcentre's Proteus software.  Please note that I have never created a spice model.

Comment: The main page for the '324 at ti.com has (scroll way down) a link for PSpice models. You may have to adapt the model files for syntax differences between PSpice and your SPICE.

Comment: Would the model available from LT not be adequate?www.linear.com/designtools/software/

Comment: Also, the tags you used had nothing to do with the question you asked. I've re-tagged for you.

Comment: @user28910, LT doesn't make a '324 device. Are you sure they provide a SPICE model for it?

Comment: THE LM234 IS NOT AN OPAMP! The LM234 is a constant current source that can be used as a temperature sensor. It IS made by LT, among others.

Answer (score 2):

There is a SPICE model of the LM334 [here](http://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceIV/examples/LtSpicePlus/Miscel/LM334%20Current%20Source/lm334.sub), which is part of the same family (LM134,LM234,LM334) and may be suitable for your use.
Incidentally, this came from LTWiki, which has some very useful info/links to large libraries (with many many extra models) and advanced LTspice use.